# Serverless.yml - Epilogue

Tags: serverless-framework

One magical day I found a reference to an 'epilogue' key to be used in the `Serverless.yml` file.  It's the best.  We use it to cleanup after testing that occurs inside our CI/CD pipeline.

```
- name: Test Integration
dependencies:
  - Deploy Dev
task:
  jobs:
    - name: Test endpoints
      commands:
        - cache restore
        - checkout
        - sem-version python 3.8
        - cd integration_tests
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
        - // our various testing scripts... 

  epilogue:
    always:  // This runs, no matter what. There are other options!!
      commands:
        - python3 99_cleanup.py
  secrets:
    - name: secret_things_go_here
```

Today, I don't want `epilogue: always:` , but rather `epilogue: when it doesn't fail:` .  I cannot find one shred of documentation about this option. Nothing to even explain how I got here in the first place.

Oh, internet: How do I run something only when my tests have passed?

Answer (score 0):

WOO!

I was barking up the wrong tree.  The solution is within SemaphoreCI, not Serverless.

https://docs.semaphoreci.com/reference/pipeline-yaml-reference/#the-epilogue-property

Options include: `on_pass` and `on_fail`.

Whew.